# How can I pass in updated values of a center of a ball into my fragment shader?

Tags: opengl

Here are my main and vertex and fragment shaders. I'm very close to getting this to work. My fragment shader needs to calculate f based on the updated center from my update_balls function. I'm not sure how to do this.

```
#include "Angel.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef Angel::vec4 vec4_t;
typedef Angel::vec3 vec3_t;
typedef Angel::vec2 vec2_t;

// the data structure of a 2D ball
typedef struct {
    vec2_t center;
    float radius;
    float currentTime;
    vec2_t velocity;
    vec2_t vertices[4];
    vec4_t color;   
} ball_t;

// the boundary
typedef enum {
    LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM, NONE
} boundary_t;

//the number of balls
int theNumBalls = 0;

//the ball array using the STL vector
vector<ball_t> theBalls;

//the program object
GLuint theProgram = 0;

//the minimal and maximal radiuses
const float theMinRadius = 0.05;
const float theMaxRadius = 0.5;

//the window size
const int   theWinWidth = 512;
const int   theWinHeight = 512;

//the time interval for advecting balls
const float theTimeInterval = 0.005;

//create a new 2D ball where the center is (x, y) and the radius
ball_t new_ball(float x, float y, float radius)
{
    ball_t ball;

    ball.center = vec2_t(x, y);
    ball.radius = radius;

    ball.vertices[0] = vec2_t(ball.center.x - ball.radius, ball.center.y - ball.radius);
    ball.vertices[1] = vec2_t(ball.center.x + ball.radius, ball.center.y - ball.radius);
    ball.vertices[2] = vec2_t(ball.center.x + ball.radius, ball.center.y + ball.radius);
    ball.vertices[3] = vec2_t(ball.center.x - ball.radius, ball.center.y + ball.radius);

    //random color
    ball.color = vec4_t((float)rand()/RAND_MAX, (float)rand()/RAND_MAX, (float)rand()/RAND_MAX, 1.0f);

    //random velocity
    ball.velocity = normalize(vec2(((float)rand()/RAND_MAX) - 0.5f, ((float)rand()/RAND_MAX) - 0.5f));

    return ball;
}

//return the boundary edge if collision
boundary_t collision_boundary(ball_t &ball)
{
    return NONE;
}

void renderBitmapString(float x, float y, void *font, string str) 
{
  glRasterPos2f(x,y);
  for (string::iterator c = (&str)->begin(); c != (&str)->end(); ++c) 
  {
    glutBitmapCharacter(font, *c);
  }
}

 // update the position or size of the balls
void update_balls()
{

    //change the size of a new ball if pressing the left button

    //or advect the ball according to the ball's velocity
    //string a ("UpdateBallsTest");
    //renderBitmapString(20, 20, GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, a);


    for (int i = 0; i < theNumBalls; i++) {

    theBalls[i].center = vec2_t(theBalls[i].center.x + theBalls[i].velocity.x * theTimeInterval, theBalls[i].center.y + theBalls[i].velocity.y * theTimeInterval);

    //assign the uniform center
    GLuint nCenter = glGetUniformLocation(theProgram, "vCenter");
    glUniform2f(nCenter, theBalls[i].center.x, theBalls[i].center.y);
        theBalls[i].vertices[0] =  vec2_t(theBalls[i].vertices[0].x + (theBalls[i].velocity.x * theTimeInterval), theBalls[i].vertices[0].y + (theBalls[i].velocity.y * theTimeInterval));
        theBalls[i].vertices[1] =  vec2_t(theBalls[i].vertices[1].x + (theBalls[i].velocity.x * theTimeInterval), theBalls[i].vertices[1].y + (theBalls[i].velocity.y * theTimeInterval));
        theBalls[i].vertices[2] =  vec2_t(theBalls[i].vertices[2].x + (theBalls[i].velocity.x * theTimeInterval), theBalls[i].vertices[2].y + (theBalls[i].velocity.y * theTimeInterval));
        theBalls[i].vertices[3] =  vec2_t(theBalls[i].vertices[3].x + (theBalls[i].velocity.x * theTimeInterval), theBalls[i].vertices[3].y + (theBalls[i].velocity.y * theTimeInterval));


    }
     //change the ball's velocity according to the return value of collision_boundary 
}


// OpenGL initialization
void init()
{
    //create a inital ball
    ball_t ball = new_ball(0, 0, 0.05);
    theBalls.push_back(ball);
    theNumBalls = theBalls.size();

    // Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
    theProgram = InitShader("vshader02.glsl", "fshader02.glsl");
    glUseProgram(theProgram);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 ); 
}

void mydisplay( void )
{
    update_balls();

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    for (int i = 0; i < theNumBalls; i++) {

        //assign the uniform variabe color
        GLuint nColor = glGetUniformLocation(theProgram, "vColor");
        glUniform4f(nColor, theBalls[i].color.x, theBalls[i].color.y, theBalls[i].color.z, theBalls[i].color.w);

        //render the ball as a qaud
        GLuint nPosition = glGetAttribLocation(theProgram, "vPosition");

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertexAttrib2fv(nPosition, theBalls[i].vertices[0]);
        glVertexAttrib2fv(nPosition, theBalls[i].vertices[1]);
        glVertexAttrib2fv(nPosition, theBalls[i].vertices[2]);
        glVertexAttrib2fv(nPosition, theBalls[i].vertices[3]);
        glEnd();
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}

void mymouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    //create a new ball under the curret mouse position if pressing the left button
}

void myidle()
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(theWinWidth, theWinHeight);

    glutCreateWindow( "Derek Meyer 73379861" );

    glewInit();

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(mydisplay);
    glutMouseFunc(mymouse);
    glutIdleFunc(myidle);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

```
/////////VSHADER

#version 150

in vec2 vPosition;
uniform vec2    vCenter;
out vec4 color;

void main() 
{
gl_Position = vec4(vCenter, 0.0, 1.0);
color = gl_Position;
}
```

```
/////////// FSHADER

#version 150
uniform vec4    vColor;
uniform vec2    vCenter;

in vec4 color;

out vec4    FragColor;

void main() 
{ 
float f = sqrt(((color.x - vCenter.x) * (color.x - vCenter.x)) + ((color.y - vCenter.y)               * (color.y - vCenter.y)));     
if (f < 0.043)
    FragColor = vColor;
else if (f < 0.05)
    FragColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
else
    FragColor = vec4(0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I've copied your code into the question for you, but in the future please use the editing tools to format your code into your question.

Comment: You're already using uniforms to upload color to your fragment shader, couldn't you use another uniform to upload the ball center in the same manner? Or what part is giving you trouble?

Comment: I can try and do that, I guess i just need to figure out how to calculate what i need from that point then.  Oh and sorry about the code problem, next time i will make sure to do it this way.

Comment: I added the uniform to upload the ball center, but im having trouble figuring out how to calculate my moving ball based on the updated center.

Comment: What do you mean 'calculate the moving ball'? If you're drawing the ball, you can just move it by adding the ball's center to the vPosition.

Comment: I'm coloring the rectangle based on the distance from a "center" point.  It draws the ball correctly at 0,0 but i need to figure out how to make it relative for when the center coord is changed.  This is done in the FShader.  Im not sure how to do this.

Comment: Trying to simply use the distance formula between the center that im updating and color in my fragment shader.  Still nothing :(